# Matching incremental digits in numbers

Tags: regex, backreference, capturing-group

After googling many days about the issue, finally I am posting this question here and hoping to get it solved by experts here; I am looking for the regex pattern that can match incremental back references. Let me explain:

For number `9422512322`, the pattern `(\d)\1` will match `22` two times, and I want the pattern (something like `(\d)\1+1`) that matches `12` (`second digit` is equal to `first digit + 1`)

In short the pattern should match all occurrence like `12`, `23`, `34`, `45`, `56`, etc... There is no replacement, just matches required.

Comment: And you forgot to specify what language you're using ?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
/01|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89/
```

It isn't sexy but it gets the job done.

Comment: This regexp won't match "23" in the substring "123" because it first matches "12". The current position of the match operation will be placed after the "2" once it matches "12" and therefore it will not able to see "23". You might be able to get around this problem using [zero-width positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: @SamChoukri: 2 things: First of all, finding overlapping matches is not an issue with this specific regular expression, but rather an issue with regular expressions in general, regardless of the pattern. Secondly, you can work around it by using the expression in a loop where you find the next match using a start position of the beginning of the previous match plus 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```regex
(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9))+.
```

This will match:

- Any `0`s which are followed by `1`s, or
- Any `1`s which are followed by `2`s, or
- Any `2`s which are followed by `3`s, ...

Multiple times `+`, then match the corresponding character `.`.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/sS1iW9/1), and the match is:

```
12345555567877785
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run code within Perl regular expressions that can
control the regex execution flow.  But, this is not likely
to be implemented anywhere else to this degree.

PCRE has some program variable interaction, but not like Perl.
(Note - to do overlap finds, replace the second `( \d )` with `(?=( \d ))`
 then change print statement to `print "Overlap Found  $1$3\n";`

If you use Perl, you can do all kinds of math-character relationships that can't be
done with brute force permutations.

- Good luck!

Perl example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dig2;
while ( "9342251232288 6709090156" =~
          /
               (
                    ( \d )
                    (?{ $dig2 = $^N + 1 })
                    ( \d )
                    (?(?{
                         $dig2 != $^N
                      })
                         (?!)
                    )
               )
          /xg )
{
    print "Found  $1\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Found  34
Found  12
Found  67
Found  01
Found  56
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in Perl, using positive lookahead assertions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $number = "9422512322";

my @matches = $number =~ /(0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9))/g;

# We have only matched the first digit of each pair of digits.
# Add "1" to the first digit to generate the complete pair.
foreach my $first (@matches) {
  my $pair = $first . ($first + 1);
  print "Found: $pair\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Found: 12
Found: 23
```